# Sorting words on same line in file using sort()

Tags: c++, sorting

Is there a way to sort words alphabetically that appear on the same line? I know that if I have words on a new line I am able to sort them easily using:

```
vector<string> file;
string line;
file.clear();
ifstream infile("foo.txt", ios_base::in);
infile.seekg(3);
while (getline(infile, line)){
    file.push_back(line);
}
sort(file.begin(), file.end());
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("foo.txt");
for (const auto &e : file) outFile << e << "\n";
```

But what if the words were on one line in the file (unseparated by spaces), for example: `catapebat`(cat ape bat). Is there an easy way to do this in C++? Would I not do the `getline` bit, since I am only grabbing one line? How would I approach this problem?

Comment: To answer the question asked: yes, there is an easy way to do this in C++.

Comment: Are you just having trouble with the basic coding required to sort words on one line? Trying to parse words not separated by spaces seems like a separate (and harder) problem.

Comment: You have non-delimited words on one line and want to read them?  Let's say instead of "cat" "ape" and "bat", it contained "a" and "done".  Without spaces, this is `adone`, and could then be split in a different way as "ad" and "one".  What do you do in ambiguous cases like this?  Is there a dictionary of allowable words?

Comment: Right now my problem is sorting words that appear on one line. I am still trying to figure out how I'd do the parsing.

Comment: @apnorton my problem is not that involved. I am only searching for records of a specific length. So I could easily just do a split on every third character, perhaps?

Comment: Well, if none of the words are separated by spaces, what you have to do is find a file with all of the words in the english language, then write some code to figure out what words are actually in the file, put each one into a separate string, and sort them. No idea what you expect to do when there's ambiguity. "airplane" could be one word, or two words, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `getline` to read a line.
2. Create an `istringstream` from the string you just read
3. Read words from there into a `vector<string>`
4. Sort the words in that vector

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting a dictionary of words like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonbcard/scrabble-bot/master/src/dictionary.txt) and comparing each word with the beginning of the string. If there's a match, you remove that many characters from the beginning of the string and store the word in an array. Repeat this until you get an array that contains all the words and then sort the array alphabetically.

**Note**: It might be worth going through the entire dictionary and keeping track of each matching word. Once the dictionary has been exhausted, select the longest match as the word before continuing on.

Comment: How would this deal with words like "airplane" or "undone", or the many other words that could be their own word, or part of a larger word?

Comment: Theoretically it would read the larger compound word as 1 word. An optimal strategy would try every combination of successful words. For example: "airplanesodapop" would result in the output: "air, plane, soda, pop" "airplane, sodapop" "air,plane,sodapop" "air,plane,sodapop"